# Centering a header while keeping current navbar positioning

Tags: html, css

Why can't I seem to center my heading on this page? I need help centering my header that says Shop on this page. Do I need to separate it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>EvenDoper.com</title>
<center>
<img src="ED1.psd"  width="719" height="159" alt="ED1">
</center>
<style>
ul {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
}
li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    right: 65%;
}
li
{
float:left;
}
a:link,a:visited
{
display:block;
width:120px;
font-weight:bold;
color:#00a651;
background-color:#FFFFFF;
text-align:center;
padding:0px;
text-decoration:none;
text-transform:uppercase;
}
a:hover,a:active
{
background-color:#FFFFFF;
}

h1 {color:#FFFFFF;}
h1 {text-align:center;}
h1
{
background-color:#00a651;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
<li><a href="shop.html">&#9889;Shop</a></li>
<li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
<br>
<h1>Shop</h1>
</html>
```

Comment: you are placing html elements outside of your `<body` tag which is invalid. make sure all your page's visible content is within the `<body>` tags.

Comment: hi, at first you should write correct code. Your image belongs inside the body-tag and it also shouldn't be a psd. Use a jpg, png or svg.

Comment: I think your caps lock is broken. The last part of your question is not in uppercase.

Comment: Use a HTML validator such as w3 to validate your markup. This will indicate any problems, i.e. major and minor problems with the way you are coding up your website.

Answer (score 1):

First, there are a lot of problems with your syntax. For example, you need to move your `<img>` code inside your `<body>` code. You also need to move the `<h1>` code at the bottom inside your `<body>` code as well. Take a look at Mozilla's [Introduction to HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Introduction) to learn more about proper HTML syntax and markup.

Second, I would recommend (along with the rest of the community, most likely) that, for so much CSS styling, you use an external CSS file. See this **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LTjSq/10/)** for a start on improving your code. Visit Mozilla's [CSS developer guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS) for some great and detailed information about CSS.

*Your **"Shop"** text is off-center for two reasons:*

**One:** Because you have some unresolved `float` entries further up the `CSS`. `CSS` stands for **`Cascading`**`Style Sheets`, which means that the styles *cascade* from top to bottom; order is important! If you `float` an element anywhere in your `CSS`, you need to `clear` it in the next element down. Otherwise, all CSS properties from there onward will have the same `float` property applied to them.

**Two:** You don't have a width set for any of your `CSS` properties, so the document is likely trying to use the    width of the `<img>` tag in your `HTML`, which is `719px`. This is making the "Shop" text centered on `width: 719px;`, basically. I've added these fixes in the JSFiddle link above, but for redundancy's sake, here is the CSS code that you should replace your `<h1>` code with:

```
h1 {
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#00a651;
}
```

Comment: Thanks guys I really appreciate the help I'm going to read up on some of the things you have suggested!

Comment: @user3362170 If this or another answer solved your question's problem, it's helpful to mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark under the vote count. Good luck! :-)

Answer (score -1):

This will help you: http://jsfiddle.net/L2nZQ/5/

But you really should start to learn the basics.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Your Title</title>
    <style>Your CSS</style>
</head>
<body>
    Your Code
</body>
</html>
```

That's a good site to do this http://www.w3schools.com/

You can verify your code here http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: I'd recommend against w3schools, since they tend to get a lot of things wrong and drag their feet for years on fixing stuff pointed out by the community.

Comment: Thanks guys I really appreciate the help I'm going to read up on some of the things you have suggested!

Comment: I recommend replacing the w3schools link. There are much better alternatives such as http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/beginners or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML. Here is some reading on some of the problems with the w3schools site: http://www.w3fools.com/